sshPut in Jenkins PL fails with AuthFail
Trying to deploy to a remote host via ssh. I have already tested the sshkey via same jenkins pipeline using bash commands and it works. echo prints the var values correctly as well. So no clue why auth is failing.
stage('Deploy to Host') {
        steps {
            sshagent(credentials: ['dev-host-ssh-key']) {
                script {
                    def remote = [:]
                    remote.name = 'remote-host'
                    remote.host = "$HOST"
                    remote.user = "$APP_USER"
                    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                    echo "HOST: ${remote.host}"
                    echo "BASE_DIR: ${env.BASE_DIR}"
    echo "APP_USER: ${remote.user}"

                    try {
        sshPut remote: remote, from: 'scripts/', into: "$BASE_DIR/$APP_USER/"
    } catch (Exception e) {
        echo "Error during sshPut: ${e.message}"
    }

Error message as caught by try/catch.please exchuse as I had no option but to add the long log as html code.


17:00:24  Identity added: /var/org/jenkins/b12adfb/workspace/3536173/some-dir@tmp/private_key_94848422121.key 
17:00:24  [ssh-agent] Started.
17:00:24  [Pipeline] {
17:00:24  [Pipeline] script
17:00:24  [Pipeline] {
17:00:24  [Pipeline] echo
17:00:24  HOST: correct_host_echoed
17:00:24  [Pipeline] echo
17:00:24  BASE_DIR: correct_dir_echoed
17:00:24  [Pipeline] echo
17:00:24  APP_USER: correct_user_echoed
17:00:24  [Pipeline] sshPut
17:00:25  [Pipeline] echo
17:00:25  Error during sshPut: Auth fail
17:00:25  [Pipeline] sshCommand
17:00:25  [Pipeline] }
17:00:25  [Pipeline] // script
17:00:25  [Pipeline] }
17:00:25  $ ssh-agent -k
17:00:25  unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
17:00:25  unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
17:00:25  echo Agent pid 1471169 killed;
17:00:25  [ssh-agent] Stopped.
17:00:25  [Pipeline] // sshagent
17:00:25  [Pipeline] }
17:00:25  [Pipeline] // stage
17:00:25  [Pipeline] stage
17:00:25  [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
17:00:25  [Pipeline] cleanWs
17:00:25  [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
17:00:25  [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
17:00:25  [WS-CLEANUP] done
17:00:25  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
17:00:25  Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Podman-p1139181
17:00:25        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
17:00:25        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
17:00:25        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
17:00:25        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.steps.CommandStep$Execution.run(CommandStep.java:72)
17:00:25        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.sshsteps.util.SSHStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SSHStepExecution.java:84)
17:00:25        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
17:00:25        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
17:00:25        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
17:00:25        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
17:00:25        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
17:00:25  com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail




Removed ssh-agent and using withCredentials.
